# Call more than 1 url simultaneously in Android through Asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to call more than one url and get the response from that with AsyncTask. Currently what happens is that I pass one url to AysncTask and then get the response of that and after that call another url. What I want to have is to pass all the urls at a time since doInBackground does take an array as argument. Once all the 3 urls are called get the response of each one of them.

Comment: Instead use Java thread to call more than 1 url and Handler to update UI instead of using AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that passing array of url in doInBackground and setting the return type for results as String[]. That gave me the response of each url called in string array in postExecute.

Anyways, Thanks for taking the time out and replying to the posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create threads inside `doInBackground` and then call the `join` method on each one of them. You'd probably be better served by a thread pool though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple AsyncTask objects and execute them in parallel - assuming all URLs just have to fetch data.